# Checkbox collection in strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I use MVC 4 and I have the below model defined and use the same in View.

I want to show item in a view and render checkbox for each city. So user can select multiple city for a perticular item.

```
public class City
{
int id{get;set;}
string name{get;set;}
}
public class Item
{
int id{get;set;}
List<City> cities{get;set;}
}

public class ItemController{

public ActionResult Save(Item item){
 List<city> selectedCitirs=item.cities; // here null

 return View();
}

public ActionResult Get(int id){

Item item=Service.GetItem(id);

return View(item);

}

}

@model item

@foreach(City c in item.cities){

@Html.CheckBoxFor(c=>c.name)

}
```

> In a controller i would like to get the selected cities name and want
>   to store in a DB like city1,city2,city3 format.

**But controller not giving item.cities. How to do?**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@model Item

@for (int i=0; i < Model.cities.Length; ++i) 
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.cities[i].name)
}
```

See also:

- [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)